# any way of justifying single paragraph lines?

Tags: jquery, css

;Is it possible?

I have many single lined paragraphs and they all need to be at most 1 line (due to various functions I have on each paragraph). I can set them all to a width with css, or (what I have at the moment):

```
var max = 0;
$(this).find('p').each(function(){
    if ($(this).width() > max)
        max = $(this).width();    
    });
    $(this).find('p').width(max);
});

text-align: justify; <<< does nothing to one line
```

But is there a way to justify one line? Without or with letter spacing calculations? Or working css3 solutions?

Comment: basically you want to space-out all words in a one-liner paragraph?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5kxP/

Comment: i found this article http://www.css3.com/css-text-justify/ and this in w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp which describes the effect you want - but they don't seem work in my browser (chrome).

Comment: @Joseph yes tried all of them! & -webkit- too!

Answer (score 3):

I knew there would [be an answer](http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/css/css-one-line-justify.html) using `:after`.

```
p {
    text-align: justify;
}
p:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5kxP/1/

Simple and effective. Props to [Vjeux](http://blog.vjeux.com/) for the solution.

Comment: sure is a nice solution however I would like to toggle this justify with jQuery & this option wouldn't work for :after! or would it?

Comment: Good idea, just thought of it too. You mean toggleClass! thanks

Comment: @JaredFarrish Your fiddle is cool! I guess it could be cooler with animate! check this out [http://heychinaski.com/jquery/characterJustifyAnimated.html](http://heychinaski.com/jquery/characterJustifyAnimated.html) only that it takes a long time to load and only works on new versions of ff not webkit because it uses letter-spacing with percentages but webkit rounds them off to the full px

Comment: @webestdesigns - Psuedo-elements are (IMO) a little bizarre but really handy when you need them. Pretty much, you can "add content" and then style it like regular elements, so in this case you add content and tell the browser to display it in a way where you can make it expand to the leftover width after the end of the text. See [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/), [here](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/), and [here](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) for more information.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Stuck at a problem that this solution causes an extra line break!

Comment: @webestdesigns - I just noticed that there's a problem with the fact that, to make justify work, the element actually has to have two lines. I resolved this with a static height (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5kxP/4/). You'll have to take that into account if you don't want that extra whitespace below the one-line paragraphs.

Comment: @webestdesigns - `justify` was designed to work with paragraphs of more than one line in presentation. Whatever it is you're describing, I think you'll need to find a way to make it work with an inner element with the justify and height applied or something. That's the cost of using `justify`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that works. Like I mentioned above, you can determine the height of a 1-line paragraph and run this jquery on any paragraphs smaller.  InnerWrap your paragraph with SPAN, this will allow you to get the width of the line of text.

Next find the difference between the P width and SPAN width, this will give you the spacing from the end of the line to the edge. You can then divide this by the number of spaces in the text, giving you the word-spacing you'll need to justify your line.

HTML, innerWrap all your P tags with span: (or you can do this with jquery too)

```
<p><span>This is my one line paragraph</span></p>
```

jQuery, do some math:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var pHeight = $(this).height();
    var pWidth = $(this).width();

    if (pHeight <= 20) {
        // Get the width of the span:
        var spanWidth = $(this).find('span').width();

        // Get the width difference between the P and Span
        var widthDiff = pWidth - spanWidth;

        // Count # of spaces:
        var spaces = $(this).html().split(' ').length - 1;

        // Divide to find word spacing:
        var spacing = widthDiff / spaces;

        $(this).css('word-spacing',spacing);
    }
});​
```

Check it out on JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wjmZP/3/

Comment: thanks & wil have a look soon, is there any other way other than adding spans (already have functions on spans!)?

Comment: May I ask why you are care about the height?

Comment: The width of a paragraph will be the same whether it's one line or 2 or 10. (it's 100% of it's container) The height of a paragraph will change with the # of lines it has. If we know each line is about 18px tall, any height between 18px and 35px will indicate that the paragraph contains only one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to determine the max height of a one-line paragraph, let's say it's 24px.

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var pHeight = $(this).height();
    if (pHeight <= 24) {
        $(this).addClass('justify');
    }
});

// css
p.justify { text-align: justify; }
```

Once you find that magic height number, you should be fine.

Comment: thanks but I don't understand how that will help since css justification only works on multiple lines?

Comment: Hmm, didn't know that css justify had that limitation, but it makes sense now that I think of it.

Comment: @Sparky672 no such limitation, because it dosn't apply to one line! right. but the question is if that too can be achieved!

Comment: @Sparky672 - Whether or not it's explicitly stated in the specs, Firefox at least does not justify a single line of text.